# How to plot a graph (e.g. u-shape) to show the non-linear relationship in panel data gression?

Tags: python, r, regression, quadratic

I am a freshman in doing regerssion and also in using python / r
I am now studying the non-linear relationship between ESG performance and Financial Performance of companies, with a set of panel data and the following equation:

```
ROA = C(1) + C(2)*ENV + C(3)*ENV2 + C(4)*SOC + C(5)*SOC2 + C(6)*GOV + 
             C(7)*GOV2 + C(8)*LNA + C(9)*LEV + C(10)*PB + C(11)*LNOE
```

ENV2, SOC2 & GOV2 are the quadratic terms for ENV, SOC & GOV respectively,
and C(8)-C(11) are control variables.

I would like to plot a graph to show the marginal effect of ENV/SOC/GOV on ROA, so my question is
how can I do that the plot the u-shaped or inverse u-shaped fitting curve via python or r?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I suspect the downvote is from someone who doubts that you have actually done any of the work needed to set this problem up, much less having done the regression. You need tor read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`plot_cap()` function from the `marginaleffects` package for `R`](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects) (disclaimer: I am the author). For example, here is a model with a quadratic term:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

# simulate
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + x^2 + rnorm(100)

# fit
mod <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = mtcars)

# plot
plot_cap(mod, condition = "x")
```

[image]